# Temporary power pole new home construction

Tags: electrical

Building in Gaston county NC. Called both power company and county. Power co. told me to call county and county said call power co. My question , can I use a 4x4x16 post 36 in ground with a 60amp 2 brk box.Just trying to get everything in place before we start with the permit process. Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; let's see if one of our pros can help you. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newcomers do.

Comment: Where I have worked the minimum provisions for temporary services are usually determined by the utility energizing the service. Gaston County has multiple service providers. The utility where I have done most work the pole would meet minimum, but the meter base and panel would be 200A amp. Also be aware some States require a permit before starting electrical work.

Comment: The utility makes the rules here. The size of the pole is based on the distance from the line, in my area a 12’above grade a 4x4  is only good for ~20’ I normally use a 6x6 , but it needs to be 12’ (not crossing a roadway)  a master electrician can approve a temp service here but a home owner needs a permit.

Comment: Who *is* your utility?  If you tell us that, I can have a go at digging up their service regulations, which should specify this sort of thing.

Comment: You just specced it like it's a fence post.  That might make sense if the supply comes in *underground*.  If it's delivered via overhead line, you need more of a *telephone pole* because it must endure *considerable* side load from the service drop...

Comment: Yes, is service in your area overhead (power poles with wires hanging from them) or underground (buried wires with junction boxes set into the ground)?